# how to override __getattribute__ and __setattr__ in dataclasses

Tags: properties, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to override the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods of a dataclass. For a single object it all works like intended but every other instance then inherits from the first instance.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, ClassVar


@dataclass
class StatusInfo:

    details: ClassVar[List[str]] = []
    exit_code: SimulationExitCode = None
    text: str = ""

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "text":
            return "---".join(self.details)
        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "text":
            self.details.extend([value])
        else:
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Console output

```
from api.info import StatusInfo
s = StatusInfo(text='as')
StatusInfo(exit_code=None, text='as')
ss = StatusInfo(text='hhh')
StatusInfo(exit_code=None, text='as------hhh')
```

I suspect it has to do with how dataclasses inheritance works. The documentation states

> When the dataclass is being created by the dataclass() decorator, it looks through all of the class’s base classes in reverse MRO (that is, starting at object) and, for each dataclass that it finds, adds the fields from that base class to an ordered mapping of fields.

So what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're using details as a ClassVar. It's value will be shared among all instances. This has nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: Is it solved by changing the ClassVar?

Comment: I had come to the same conclusion in the meanwhile. Somehow I had a wrong understanding of `ClassVar`s. Thanks for your input, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe another problem (distinct from the usage of `ClassVar` mentioned in the comments) is with a mutable default argument.

The constructor generated by the `@dataclass` decorator as you've defined it includes a [mutable default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) so that a `details` list is created only once when the `StatusInfo` class is defined and not uniquely for each instantiation.

You can get around this by switching it to

```
details: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
```